# Is there a way to switch off wpf design surface in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I would like to know if there is a way to simply turn of the WPF design surface in Visual Studio 2008. I would like to have the xaml editor, but not the design surface as it slows down  the IDE, when I try to open a XAML file. For my workflow having only the source files for xaml would be a better fit as I am doing all visuals in Blend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to right-click the .xaml file and select "Open With..." then select "Source Code (Text) Editor" (optionally clicking "Set as Default" to make it the default). This will open the file in the plain XML editor (you still get syntax highlighting and IntelliSense, too).

Answer (score 4):

Tools->Text Editor->XAML->Miscellaneous  uncheck Always open documents in full XAML view

[alt text http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/WindowsLiveWriter/DisableXAMLdesignerinVisualStudio2008_118F4/image_2.png](http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/WindowsLiveWriter/DisableXAMLdesignerinVisualStudio2008_118F4/image_2.png)

The comment below informs of a catch when using this checkbox, that is it only affects files that have not been opened before. A solution from the link to the Microsoft Connect issue in the comment states that

> If you really wish to reset the
>   open/close behavior for all XAML files
>   in your project, you can achieve this
>   by closing Visual Studio, then
>   locating the SUO file adjacent to your
>   SLN file and deleting or renaming it,
>   then re-opening Visual Studio. When
>   you re-open your solution an new SUO
>   will be created and all files will be
>   treated as "new". Please note this
>   will also remove any other
>   solution-specific IDE behavior for
>   your solution.

Comment: A small node: This Option only works for files that haven´t been opened before. Visual Studio stores the last state a file was opened in and will use the state on re-open. See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/549873/option-always-open-documents-in-full-xaml-view-does-not-work-correctly